# Fitting Weibull distribution to the censored data

Tags: r, distribution, weibull, back-testing

I would like to estimate Maximum Likelihood parameters of the Weibull distribution by applying to the following data with a given censoring vector in R:

data=   9  2 11 49  7  5  3 36 30  6 62  5  3 29 29  1 13  1 24 11  9  4  7 15 11 15  1  1  1  1  1  2  6 12 12 28 14 14 57 17  4 2  3  6 21  6 16 19 28 18 19  9 59 12  3 27  8 26 19 47 68 17 15 25 25  6 54  1  2 11  4  1 36  2  5  5  3 38  3  1 10 69 1  8  3 17 21 19 11  1  6  1  1 18  2 51  6 12 11 13  3 19 16 18 28 10 26 32  6 25  1 44

cens=  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Please take a look at how to make a good reproducible example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/7306168)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Abrem`](https://rdrr.io/rforge/abrem/man/abrem-package.html) package:

```
install.packages("abrem", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

You may need to manually install an older version of RccpArmadillo if you have issues like I did:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RcppArmadillo/RcppArmadillo_0.6.100.0.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Then have at it:

```
library(abrem)

a = Abrem(fail = c(2, 11, 49, ...), susp = c(9, 44))
a = abrem.fit(a, dist = 'weibull', method.fit = 'mle')
a = abrem.conf(a) # add 90% confidence bands
plot.abrem(a) # plot the points and fit distribution
print.abrem(a) # print the results, which includes the fitted parameters
```

I may have confused your failures vs. suspensions data, but hopefully the example makes it clear where each goes.